# Should a fragment be able to change the State of a View inside the host Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

If I need to hide a view inside the Activity when a certain fragment is inflated, is it ok to let the Fragment do the State Change?

For example I have a three Fragments (FragmentA, FragmentB, FragmentC) and one Activty. The Activity have a BottomNavigation View but its visibility should be set to Gone if FragmentB is inflated inside the Activity.

If I placed the managing of the BottomNavigation Visibility inside the fragment then, I am sure that whenever that fragment is inflated the view will certainly be set to gone.

My only problem is that, if there come a time that I need to reuse that fragment and show the BottomNavigation at the same time. I wont be able to do so because the Fragment will automatically set the Visibility of the BottomNavigation to Gone.

Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, do not control the visibility of the BottomNavigation inside the Fragment, do it inside the Activity with a **callback**. 
[read about callback this in part **"Creating event callbacks to the activity"**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=en)

Fragments should be self-sufficient and should not know anything about other Fragments and Activites.

Comment: I did get what you are pointing out here and I believe it is correct but, I also have encountered this issue where I use a shared element transition for fragments. Now if you are familiar you have to set the set the setReorderingAllowed to true. I don't really know whats ahppening and how the fragments are create and how their lifecycle are triggered but when doing popBackStack(<name>, INCLUSIVE), the state of the View Managed by the fragment (either via call back or directly) remains the same.

Comment: I assume that since reordering allowed allow the fragment to exist at the same time and not ensure that the whole life cycle of the fragment gets called, the call to change view state gets overlapped by the other fragments or not get called at all.